# MacOS web apps font has changed. How to get it back to normal?

Tags: fonts

Today I installed a couple of fonts via Font Books app, Open Sans Condensed and Peddana.

Now all my webapps look horrible. One of them Ryver and the other Whats App. I want to get it back to normal but I don't know how, maybe I touched something wile installing the other fonts.

Any idea?

[image: Whats App image that illustrates the difference]

As can be seen in the picture, the text is really small, while the options are looking normal in the whatsapp webapp.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Open Sans Condensed replaced Open Sans, I don't know why. To solve it just uninstall both and install Open Sans again.